# How can I rename SharePoint 2007 Content, Config and Search databases?

Tags: sharepoint

Trying to do a test with development virtuals and need to move the databases to a dedicated DB server (they are currently located on the development virtuals).

As part of the move I need to rename the databases.

Is there an easy way to rename the SharePoint databases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not officially supported.  There's a [KB article about the supported database changes](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/841057/en-us).  You can [use PSConfig](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263093.aspx) to do it, but it's not what I would call easy.

Answer (score 0):

Brent's right in that you don't want to go mucking about with the SharePoint databases, especially on a production system.  If you do want to rename the databases on a non-production system (knowing that you may not be able to get support directly from Microsoft if you do so), I have put up a step-by-step here: http://blogs.technet.com/seanearp/archive/2009/03/14/renaming-crazy-sharepoint-database-names.aspx

If your real question is how to move the databases to a separate SQL server, the steps are documented on TechNet here:

Move All Databases: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512725.aspx
Move Content Databases: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263037.aspx

-Sean